# IE6 Javascript Error at Char: 21007

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I am at my wits end, an page for one of my clients is throwing an error in IE6

```
Line: 3
Char: 21007
Error: Expected ':'
Code: 0
```

this is line 3

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I thought about 'what if ie6 counts the first line as the first line with content', that would make line 3

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

the only file i have with that many columns is `jquery-1.5.2.min.js` and ive tried swapping out versions and the error stays the same.

I dont understand what the error is coming from.

---

**Turns out this is an issue with the AddThis widget. The fix for my specific issue is documented here http://www.addthis.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=29776**

---

Comment: Does the error go away if you just remove the jquery script tag?

Comment: Usually the line that is displayed in the error alert has nothing to do with the actual error. There is nothing wrong with your XHTML declaraion.

Comment: the doctype should be the first line, ie6 does not understand <?xml or comments before the doctype

Comment: 1) Install the [Microsoft Script Debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=2f465be0-94fd-4569-b3c4-dffdf19ccd99&displaylang=en).  2) In IE6, go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced, and UNCHECK the two "Disable Script Debugging" marks.  Reload the page, you should now have a more meaningful error, and a debugger.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the javascript include:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=yourusername"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js?pub=yourusername"></script>
```